# Extract <img> and <iframe> tags from existing Mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, database, merge

I'm merging a website into a complete new structure. They used mysql to store all their content but they inlined images, video, etc ... in the same field as the content itself.

Of course, in the new structure I have a picture table, video fields, etc ...

Sombeone have a clue how to extract (and remove) the  and  tags from the original content ?

Comment: `$html = preg_replace("/<iframe(.*?)>|<\/iframe(.*?)>/", "", $html);` Use the same thing for <img>

Comment: Select the content, load it into a `DOMDocument`, find the iframe and img elements (see `getElementsByTagName`), remove the element and store its contents elsewhere and update the DB with the result of `saveHTML()`